# Почему HTML думает, что "chucknorris" - цвет?

Tags: html, браузер, цвета

Почему совершенно случайные строки распознаются как цвет, когда введены как фоновый цвет в HTML?

Например, `bgcolor="chucknorris"` предоставляет **красный цвет**:

```html
<body bgcolor="chucknorris"> test </body>
```

Наоборот, `bgcolor="chucknorr"` предоставляет **жёлтый фон**:

```html
<body bgcolor="chucknorr"> test </body>
```

Поведение одно и тоже в разных браузерах и операционных системах. Что тут происходит?

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8318911/why-does-html-think-chucknorris-is-a-color

Answer (score 2):

Это пережиток времён [Netscape](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netscape_Navigator):

> Пропущенные символы интерпретируются как 0[...]. Неправильный символ просто интерпретируется как 0. Например, значения #F0F0F0, F0F0F0, #FxFxFx, и FxFxFx одинаковы.

Это из статьи [*A little rant about Microsoft Internet Explorer's color parsing*](http://scrappy-do.blogspot.com/2004/08/little-rant-about-microsoft-internet.html) (на английском), которая покрывает это очень подробно, включая меняющиеся длины цветов, и т. д.

Если применить правила по очереди из статьи, мы получаем следующее:

1. Заменить все некорректные шестнадцатеричные символы на 0:

   ```
   chucknorris становится c00c0000000
   ```
2. Дополнить до следующего общего количества символов, кратного 3:

   ```
   c00c 0000 0000
   ```
3. Разделить на три равные группы, каждая из которых представляет соответствующий цветовой компонент цвета RGB:

   ```
   RGB (c00c, 0000, 0000)
   ```
4. Обрезать каждую группу справа до двух символов.

Что в конечном итоге, даёт следующий результат:

```
RGB (c0, 00, 00) = #C00000 или RGB(192, 0, 0)
```

---

Пример, демонстрирующий атрибут `bgcolor`, чтобы показать этот «удивительный» эффект:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="chucknorris" cellpadding="8" width="100" align="center">chuck norris</td>
    <td bgcolor="mrt"         cellpadding="8" width="100" align="center" style="color:#ffffff">Mr T</td>
    <td bgcolor="ninjaturtle" cellpadding="8" width="100" align="center" style="color:#ffffff">ninjaturtle</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="sick"  cellpadding="8" width="100" align="center">sick</td>
    <td bgcolor="crap"  cellpadding="8" width="100" align="center">crap</td>
    <td bgcolor="grass" cellpadding="8" width="100" align="center">grass</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

Это также отвечает на другую часть вопроса: Почему `bgcolor="chucknorr"` создаёт жёлтый цвет? Если мы применим правила, получается:

```
c00c00000 => c00 c00 000 => c0 c0 00 [RGB(192, 192, 0)]
```

Что и даёт жёлтый цвет. Поскольку длина строки - 9 символов, мы оставляем вторую "C" на этот раз, следовательно, она попадает в окончательное значение цвета.

<sub><sup>*Перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8333464/21493925) от [@dash](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1073107/dash) на [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com)*.</sup></sub>